# How can I recover from a mistake in installing a plugin?

Tags: moodle

I mistakenly put the plugin I wanted to install into the `mod` folder, instead of putting it in `mod/local`.

I clicked on install and got an error, and then I realized my mistake. Now, when I put the plugin into `mod/local`, I don't get shown any plugins in the list of plugins requiring my attention on the "Plugins check" page, and deleting it also has no effect.

How can I recover my Moodle installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Moodle plugins should ever be installed to [moodle folder]/mod/local.

Activity plugins should be installed to [moodle folder]/mod/[pluginfolder].

Local plugins should be installed to [moodle folder]/local/[pluginfolder].

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing the plugin within the `/local` directory? `/mod/local` would be the location for a module plugin called "local".